# BingBot hitting multiple subdomains all at the same time, causing panic

Tags: web-crawlers, bingbot, multi-subdomains

I have a site with multiple subdomains. On certain hours of the day, Bingbots would gather at my site and do a massive scan like this:

```
01:23:11 a.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.A
01:23:11 b.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.A
01:23:11 c.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.A
01:23:11 d.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.A
01:23:12 e.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.A
01:23:12 f.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 403 Bot.A
01:23:12 g.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 403 Bot.A
01:23:22 h.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.B
01:23:22 i.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.B
01:23:22 j.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.B
01:23:22 k.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.B
01:23:23 l.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 200 Bot.B
01:23:23 m.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 403 Bot.B
01:23:23 n.example.com GET /index HTTP/1.1 403 Bot.B
```

As the bots are scanning across multiple subdomains, the `Crawl-delay: 1` directive in `robots.txt` would have no effect on such behaviour. The server defence mechanism would kick in and block these crawlers by issuing 403 errors.

Is there a way to spread out BingBot's crawling evenly? The default [crawl pattern](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302) on Bing's webmaster tool doesn't seem to be followed.

Comment: Check the requester domain name or IP address. I bet it is not Microsoft. Can you update us with one or more domain names and/or IP addresses?

Comment: @closetnoc, I am quite sure those IPs are from Microsoft as I have been running `whois` and `host` on them. Example a whois on `207.46.13.100` says "NetName: MICROSOFT-GLOBAL-NET". A PTR lookup says "msnbot-207-46-13-100.search.msn.com". Also, the webmaster tool reported these 403 errors.

Comment: Okay. I am a bit surprised but I believe you. I have seen a lot of spoofing these days and rogue spiders/bot use Bing as an agent name a lot. I thought Bing was like Google where the requests would come about every 2 +/- seconds unless stated otherwise. You may want to up your crawl rate to 2 seconds or remove it all together to see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Vincent from Bing Webmaster Tools and I noticed your post.

First of all, I'm sorry to hear about the problem you are having with our crawler's crawl activity across your subdomains. I am sure we can do better.

Couple of things:

I noticed you mentioned crawl pattern setting in Webmaster Tools wasn't working for. The reason is that when using a Crawl-delay: directive in robots.txt and - this directive always gets precedence over any Crawl Control settings in the Bing Webmaster Tools, which is why this isn't working as expected (see the note in http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302).

On the other hand, since having to mitigate this through several subdomain-specific robots.txt with different crawl-delay: directives isn't optimal I don't have a good self-service solution here which is why I suggest you contact Bing Webmaster Support and share the domain/sub-domain information so they can pass it to the right team to take a closer look (they may ask for server logs to help with the investigation).

To contact Webmaster Support go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=261881, fill out the required fields, and in the "What type of problem do you have?" dropdown, select "Under-Crawling or Over-Crawling inquiry" and describe the problem you are seeing.  Even if they don't come back with a personalized response immediately (it can take 24-48 hrs.), this should at least get the ball rolling.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters - thanks for your input here!

Comment: Hi Vincent, thank you for your attention. Just to clarify some details. The webmaster crawl pattern has always been at the default crawl rate with default uniform pattern. I was having 403 errors from BingBot before I decided to add in the crawl delay directive, hoping to mitigate the problem. But the situation did not improve. I will file a report and see how it goes from there. Having said that, it would be good if BingBot can be optimized to crawl one subdomain at a time to avoid overloading websites with multiple subdomains since there is no good way to control this with robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, MSN Bots have always been too unruly for robots.txt and they bring no discernable traffic advantage. For the past three years I have become very intolerant of their terrible behaviour. And yes, they are from Microsoft.

- 403 them with RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} in .htaccess
- Use fail2ban or mod_security to block or rate-limit-block them
- Both of the above
- Collect the log data and null route them

They do not deserve access.

Comment: I have not had any trouble with the bot, but unless you are listed in Bing, they are useless and waste a lot of resources I grant you that! Bing is cutting it's own throat with the notion of being choosy. Google did not become #1 by being choosy. It got to be #1 by indexing as much as it could day after day after day and giving newer and smaller sites a shot to compete on merit on scale rather than waiting till they got big and had a lot of backlinks. It is a foolish strategy. At least that is how I see it.